# Editing an ordered list of short strings

Tags: lists, input-fields, winforms

I need to provide a means for our marketing team to add/remove/edit an ordered list of short descriptive strings (0 - 8 strings total).  The strings are typically less than 50 characters but we need to support up up 100 characters.

[image: Ordered list of 'smallish' strings]

My stopgap solution is shown above.  This works well enough if they are editing an existing string, removing an existing string (I shift the list 'up' when they enter a blank value) or are adding/removing from the end of the list.  However, if they need to insert an item they are forced to manually cut-n-paste existing values.  Obviously that is quite clunky.  Thankfully they don't do that all that often, so I have some time to build a 'better' solution.

I'm looking for a UI construct or mechanism that I could implement to make managing this ordered list of short strings easier.

Maybe I could just add an 'insert' button?  When pressed (and there is room for more strings), I would shift the list 'down' (from whatever item they are currently on) and pre-populate the field with a stock string ("please edit")?

FWIW, this is a C# WinForm application.  We have plans to move it to a web application but that won't happen until the end of the year.

Comment: Try using any one of these https://www.wunderlist.com/web/ or https://en.todoist.com/

Comment: I think I'm leaning towards adding an 'add' and 'remove' button to the list.  In fact, I might remove the static labels "1. 2."  and just have 0-8 text boxes with two buttons near by.  I need to play around with something once I get a moment.